# What should I mark as the purpose of my trip to the Schengen area if I have multiple different activities planned?

Tags: schengen, applications

I will be travelling to France for an academic conference and then to Spain after that for tourism.   For the academic conference, I believe that I need a business visa issued by a French consulate.  My question is, can I travel to Spain with the same visa?  If so, when filling in the Schengen visa application form, which box should I check in line 21, main purpose(s) of journey?  Should I check business or both business and tourism?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: The main purpose of your trip is **business** and yes you can travel with the same visa to Spain. At the interview you explain you will do some tourism. Or you can write it in the form. This is very normal. Without the conference you would not be going on the trip.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Just to make sure I understand what you said correctly: I can check either business, or both business and tourism.  In the first case, I will need to explain at the interview that I will be traveling in Spain for tourism.  Is that correct?

Comment: **Main** purpose is business. Just check business and then explain.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of your trip is to [visit an academic conference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53025/schengen-visa-application-academic-conference), therefore you should mark **Business** in the Schengen application form.