# Need advice before applying for Schengen (Visit to friends and family or tourist)

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, indian-citizens

I'm an Indian Passport holder and an Indian Citizen. I'm 19.

I want to travel to Germany for a week to meet a close friend (who's a German national)

Now I have every document required. Finance not a problem (dad is my sponsor) and everything is alright with that area.

The thing I need advice with they need: Leave letter of your company (if employed) or No-objection certificate of school or university (if student) and I don't have any of those two. Why? Cause I don't work (I got out of High School – 12th grade – a year back) and I'll be going aboard for my studies so I'm not a student at the moment.

Now I'm just looking for a Tourist or Visit of Friends and Family Visa.

Any Idea If I can go ahead and apply for a visa without those two (anyone) documents? I'll write my reason in the personal covering letter for sure.

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Did you get your visa without those documents?

Comment: Hello, Yes I did but I got it from San Fransisco

Answer (score 4):

If you examine the checklist provided by the [VFS in India](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/pdf/checklist_ctourism_141219.pdf)...

[image]

...you can observe the caveats against each item...

- Leave letter of your company (if employed)
- No-objection certificate of school or university (if student)

"If employed" means that you have a job with an employer from whom a leave letter can be obtained.  "If student" means you are in a school or university from which a no-objection certificate can be obtained.

Based upon what you wrote, neither of these documents apply to you.  Accordingly, you would not need to submit them and their omission will not in itself provide grounds for a refusal.

Related article: [Schengen Visa Application: tips for preparing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing)