# Does an Indian with a UK Tier 2 visa need to book flights before applying for a Schengen visa? [

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I am an Indian currently with a UK Tier 2 ICT (Work visa). From UK with family (wife and 3-year-old son) I am planning a visit as tourists to Budapest, Hungary and Prague, Czech Republic.

Do I need actually to book the flights before applying for a Schengen visa, or would just the hotel reservations (via booking.com) do?

Comment: From the linked answer, please read: "Tickets: Return flight reservations, but it is emphatically recommended not to purchase tickets outright in advance of the application. If in doubt, it's fine to include a statement that you will make a personal appearance with paid tickets when the visa is issued and you are collecting your passport. Round trip evidence is a statutory requirement without discretionary latitude."

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to pay for a hotel or flights prior to applying for your visa.Some Schengen countries require you to book your return flight but specifically say that you do not need to pay for your ticket until a visa is issued.

Comment: Evidence? Anything more useful than a one-line answer?

Comment: I have edited my answer. No country requires an air ticket to be purchased for visa application.

Comment: Can you add something to your answer that improves the information given in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing  Or alternatively explain why the question is not a duplicate and your answer fits?

Comment: I am not claiming this question to be an original. I am a relatively new user here, saw a question that I thought I knew an answer to and replied to it.

Comment: @ParminderSinghChahal, I didn't give you a down vote, but you are after all, an "Established User" on the site. Please edit to provide the right evidence supporting your answer. Thanks.