# What can I do with my UK Transit visa?

Tags: uk, europe, transit-visas, filipino-citizens

I am a Philippine passport holder currently working in Trinidad and Tobago. For my one month vacation, I am planning to pass through the Trinidad-London-Dubai-Philippines route. I am applying for UK Transit visa and thinking if I could use this to travel around Europe.

Is it possible?

Comment: See [Schengen Visa Application: tips for preparing](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing) if you wish to obtain a visa to travel around Europe.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not sure how this is a dupe, the OP wants to know if they can visit Europe with a UK transit visa

Comment: @blackbird57 See the user's comment below. They are actually wanting to visit Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of Europe is in the [Schengen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) treaty area. The UK isn't. You would need a Schengen tourist visa for sightseeing. And a transit visa isn't sufficient for a longer stay in the UK, either.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it hard to get Schengen Visa if you haven't been to other countries? My first out of the country is in Trinidad and it is for work.

Comment: @RaRa, you will have to convince the visa officials that you're no illegal immigrant. Do you have a good and steady job in Trinidad? That's the main thing.