# What are my chances of getting a tourist visa to Croatia after 3 successive rejections?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

First, I applied for a tourist visa for 16 days, showing a reservation for a hotel as I thought that visiting places nearby could be done in a single day. Also I showed my interest to meet friends I met online but didn't provide their details.

Result: visa refusal saying "Justification of purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided."

I required to reschedule my flight and changed the itinerary because of less time.

The second time, I applied right away for a tourist visa again for 9 days, showing a proper itinerary with different locations and different accommodation reservations. I added a letter to tell them about changes in the plan. I told them I wouldn't meet friends because my main purpose is tourism and I wouldn't have time to meet them.

Result: refusal with 3 points:

"proof of sufficient means of subsistence...".

"There are reasonable doubts as to the authenticity of the supporting documents or the veracity of their contents or the reliability of the statements made".

"There are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the territory of the republic of Croatia before the expiry of the visa applied for".

The third time, I applied again for a tourist visa with the same planning. And as I found that I didn't have movements in my savings account so may be it caused the issue. I added my salary account statements and other saving account statements. But I didn't have anything to prove my intention to leave the country other than my confirmed return flight, booking of final day accommodation. I thought the bank statement was issue for doubts on supporting document. So my new evidence will clear it.

Result: visa refusal with 2 points:

"There are reasonable doubts as to the authenticity of the supporting documents or the veracity of their contents or the reliability of the statements made".

"There are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the territory of the republic of Croatia before the expiry of the visa applied for".

After the third rejection I rescheduled my flights to next year. But still I am unable to find what the exact reason behind the refusal was. Recently I found that the company where I'm currently working was registered in February but I joined in January. So is it possible that they checked the company registration?

Can it be the reason of refusal of the visa application?

This year I am planning to go to a nearby country for my first international  trip. Will it be helpful for my next application? Can buying a car be evidence of property? Can having a fixed deposit of 4,000 USD be evidence of property?

How can I improve my circumstance before applying again?

I tried to contact several consultants but they even didn't answer after listening to my query.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are many questions like yours on TSE. Reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing should help

Comment: You should also read [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221) as this explains why you were refused.

Answer (score 3):

You've applied three times in quick succession, with three rejections.  You're seeing

> There are reasonable doubts as to the authenticity of the supporting
>   documents or the veracity of their contents or the reliability of the
>   statements made".

and

> "There are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the
>   territory of the republic of Croatia before the expiry of the visa
>   applied for".

The visa officer is saying that he no longer believes your explanations or your intentions.

You appear desperate, and the suspicion is that there is something going on that you're not being honest about. A fourth application now will serve only to reinforce that idea and will almost certainly result in another rejection. The consultants you have approached appear to have decided that you are a lost cause, at least for now.

Give up on Croatia for now. Cancel your flights - you're unlikely to have any success in the foreseeable future. You need to establish credible ties to your home country (an established job, own your own home or long term rental, family and friends) and a history of international travel before applying again. This could take years.

And when you do apply again consider consulting a lawyer with appropriate experience to help you draft your application.

Comment: I don't want to give up. I mean i want to try with possible evidence that i can provide like I am single son of my parents. Other than it , If i show my all FD that make total amount of 4000 USD. as well as i mentioned that i will do a trip this year. It can be good idea? Actually i dont want to waste money that i spent in buying Air Tickets. So i want to try again in end of this year. If i change purpose of visit like.. Visit to friend instead of tourism. Will it work ?

Comment: @Sho You seem to be set on getting a permanent Schengen space ban of a couple of years. At the moment, it seems the only sure thing it will happen. People should not be pointing it out for you after 3 denials in a row. Count your blessings it has not happened yet.