# What documents do my sponsor need to sponsor my touristic schengen visa and what is the form of the sponsorship letter?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am from Madagascar. I am a studying abroad in Turkey. I am on scholarship so I have to go back here in Turkey. 
And this summer, I am going in Europe. My father will be sponsoring my trip. Other than his bank statements and the sponsorship letter, what else do I need? And how is the form of the letter?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The role of your sponsor is to **confirm your source of funds**. When people travel who cannot really afford the luxury of tourism, the immediate suspicion is that their trip is an *investment* and that they plan to repay it by overstaying and working. So there are two questions:

- Why would your sponsor give you the money as a gift? That's obvious for a father, but more distant relatives would have some explaining to do.
- Can your sponsor reasonably afford to give the money as a gift and is the money legal? That requires explaining his financial situation.

Note that you will have to explain your own financial circumstances as well, even if you don't spend your own money on the trip. That's to evaluate your intention to leave the Schengen area.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you're from, which might affect things.

But you should also include some documentation of ties to your home country as proof that you will leave Schengen again.

It might be relevant to read:
[Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

and 
[Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

In a comment Traveller has pointed to:
[Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)

Comment: This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing may also be useful

Comment: @Traveller: Indeed, I've added that link to the answer, crediting you for pointing to it.