# Reapply for romanian visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, applications, romania

My Romanian visa got rejected . After how many days again I can apply ? I want to travel Romania but my visa got rejected .after how many days again I can reapply?

Comment: You _can_ generally reapply immediately, but if your circumstances have not changed since your previous application, why would the outcome be any different?

Comment: Your application was rejected for a reason, not because of random factors. If you put in the same application again, you will be rejected again, for the same reason.

Comment: Although Romania is not yet part of the Schengen area, you may find this answer helpful https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten if you’ve not already read them