# Is Invitation needed for Schengen visas?

Tags: schengen-visas, nigerian-citizens, invitation-letters

Do I also need to have a Visit Invitation for Any of the schengen territories to apply for a Visa? Kindly let me know this, or I could just apply for a Vacation and I am good?

Comment: You’ve asked several questions about how to apply for a visa. Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an explanation of why you travel, and documents supporting that explanation.

- If you are a tourist and pay for the trip yourself, you need no invitation.
- If you are visiting friends who provide housing and food, they should confirm that.
- If you are visiting a company or a scientific conference, you should have documents for that.

When you come for a vacation, you have to document that the money is yours to spend, that the amount appears reasonable for your financial circumstances, and that you have ties (best a well-paid job) to return to.

They will want to see your finances in any case, to judge your ties to your homeland.

Comment: Meaning, I would need something like a letter to document my reason for visit in any case, since I do not have who is inviting me, I have hotel reservations tho.. Pls wat u advise?

Comment: @Kunie No. You state the purpose of your visit (eg tourism) in the application, and provide documents such as your hotel reservation to show where you plan to spend your time during the visit.

Comment: @Kunle, you need a cover letter to explain your trip. This would mention the purpose (tourism) and dates and destinations (here your reservations can help). You also need evidence of legal residence for the place you're applying from if you live abroad, bank statements, payslips or tax forms, a confirmation of the vacation period from your employer, and proof of health insurance.

Comment: "You also need evidence of legal residence for the place you're applying from if you live abroad": also if you live in (and are a national of) a country with multiple consular districts, in which case you need to show that you live in the district of the consulate to which you are submitting the application.