# How do I apply for Schengen Visa from India?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

I am the first time traveler to Austria from India, but I don't know the procedure, documents, eligibility, and fees required to get the Schengen Visa India. I have checked with the Austria Embassy website but I didn't get sufficient information. So, Can anyone guide for this?

Comment: Google ? Did you google in the first instance ?

Comment: This might help you prepare https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Answer (score 3):

Seems straight forward to me, visit the [VFS Global](http://www.vfs-austria.co.in/) link.

- Select **Menu** and then the **Short Term Visa** type you need

---

> **Submission of Visa Application**
>   The visa applications can be submitted at any of the 20 centers of VFS Global all over the country. For contact details and further information regarding submission of visa application at VFS , please visit the link of [VFS Global](http://www.vfs-austria.co.in/).

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa – Österreichische Botschaft New Delhi](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/en/austrian-embassy-new-delhi/travels-to-austria/visa/)

  - [VFS Global Apply for VISA to Austria](http://www.vfs-austria.co.in/)

    - In India and Nepal (Also representing Sri Lanka, Bhutan, Bangladesh, Maldives)