# Questions about Lithuania Visas for First timer in Schengen

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, nigerian-citizens, lithuania

I have 2 questions about Lithuania Schengen visas Type C
Goes thus :

- Does Lithuania give multiple visas up to a Year for first time
  applicants applying for schengen visas?
- Secondly, Can I apply to Lithuania without invitation letters in the
  case of Tourism?

I am from Nigeria. Just concerned.

Comment: Highly unlikely you’d get a multiple entry visa if you’ve never had a Schengen visa before, or an equivalent eg Canada, UK. To visit as a tourist you typically need to provide evidence of where you’ll be staying eg confirmed hotel booking. This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing might be useful reading

Answer (score 1):

1 Maybe they have given it to some applicant. There is no sure-shot answer to this question. First time applicants mostly get visas as per their itineraries with a few days leverage for change in plans. But it is so varied that there is no general answers. For a 10 day plan, I have seen first time applicants getting  an exact 10 day visa with the exact dates, getting 30 day visas, getting 6 months visas, getting 1 year visa, getting 90 day visa. It is extremely varied. You should keep your expectation to the exact itinerary. If you get a longer visa, it's your luck.

Single and multiple entry, again depends on your itinerary and luck. If your itinerary involves going in and out of Schengen area, then multiple entry visa is issued. Visas issued for significantly longer duration than asked for as also multiple entry visas. Visas issued for short duration based on single entry itinerary can be single or multiple entry as per luck.

2 No invitation letters are required for tourism. Just attach the documents mentioned on the website.