# What are the requirements to get a short business visa to Spain?

Tags: visas, applications, spain, business-travel, azerbaijan

I am from Yemen, I live in Azerbaijan. I am working remotely in a Swedish company and every year they have a global meeting trip, this year it happen to be in Spain.

A visa is required for me to go there. I have searched online and couldn’t find official Spain embassy website in Azerbaijan so I can check requirements. In fact I am not that sure if there is Spain embassy here or no.

Can someone please help me out on steps I should do, like **where I can check requirement ? What type of visa I need ? How do I book appointment ? How long would it take to get visa ? And if there is anything I should know ?**

Comment: Your citizenship is Yemeni? Do you have a residence permit for Azerbaijan, or are you only there temporarily? Do you have a work visa for Azerbaijan? Have you asked your managers for the help and advice? According to embassypages.com, the embassy of Spain in Baku is located at Nizami Street 90A and can be contacted by telephone on 12 497 77 93 as well as by email ant.baku@maec.es. The consular section shares location as well as telephone number and email address with the embassy.

Comment: Yes I do have residence permit for Azerbaijan. I have asked some locals here they said I should apply for Schengen Visa from French embassy here. I am not sure exactly to ask .. ill email to the email you sent me.

Comment: This question about how to prepare might be helpful https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Comment: @Traveller, yes that helps .. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> La France représente la Belgique, l’Espagne, le Luxembourg, les Pays-Bas, le Portugal et la Suède pour toutes les demandes de visas de court séjour Schengen.

The [French embassy in Baku](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/az/dispositions-locales) is competent to consider and issue Schengen visas on behalf of Belgium, Spain, Luxembourg, the Netherlands, Portugal and Sweden.

Supporting documents must be submitted in French or English. The requirement for issuance of Schengen visas is broadly similar (and legally uniform) and you can consult the document list required for a French-issued Schengen visa in case of a business visit.

Answer (score 2):

The list of embassies of the [spanish government](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/en/EmbajadasConsulados/Paginas/index.aspx) states for Azerbaijan, that the competent Spanish embassy is the [Turkish](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/Ankara) one

But, the Schengen [Visa Code hanbook](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2020-06/visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf) on 1.6 says :

> **Should a Member State consulate accept an application from an applicant
> travelling to a Member State that is not present or represented in the third country
> where the applicant resides?**

> Article 5(4) entails an obligation for Member States to cooperate in order to prevent such
> situations of Member States not being present or represented and thus, this obligation is an
> obligation of means, not an obligation of result. Therefore, Member States are not obliged to
> accept visa applications that they are not competent to examine and take decisions on
> according to the rules set out above where the competent Member State is not present or
> represented.

> However, considering that this provision is contained in the article concerning the ”Member
> State competent for examining and deciding on an application”, a Member State may, in the
> absence of the normally competent Member State, agree to examine such applications in
> individual, exceptional circumstances and take a decision on it
> – for reasons of justified urgency, and
> – after having obtained the agreement of the normally responsible Member State.

This means that unless Spain has an agreement with another Schengen member (which is likely) or it has justified urgency, you can't apply for it in Azerbaijan.

I would suggest you to contact the Turkish embassy and ask for the guidance on how to apply from Azerbaijan

Comment: Locals here told me to apply from France  embassy , but thats all the info I got.