# Will my Schengen visa application get rejected?

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-rejections, proof-of-employment

I am a marine engineer from India.
I am planning a trip with my wife to Europe in Feb end. My visa appointment is on Jan 18th.
I have my travel itinerary with day to day activities and hotel reservations, flight itinerary and the other required documents.

The one thing I don't have is a letter from my company as my job is a contract based job. I also own a small business in India and I am submitting all the proofs regarding that also. But I am worried if my visa will rejected based on my employment proof as there is no letter from my company so far.
Please guide me on what else can I do to make sure I get the visa.

Comment: What type of visa are you requesting?

Comment: Which country are you applying to?

Comment: What is your prior travel history (the more you have the more positive, and vice versa). What type of work do you do (remote working for example, will not be a strong a tie as employment that *requires your physical presence* in your home country. See the graphic here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy and also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)