# How can an Indian homemaker spouse be guaranteed a Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, europe

A relative in India (a practicing doctor) wants to go on a European tour with his wife (also a doctor, but not working; she is preparing for exams). He has been told that his wife may not get a visa since she is not working, and even if she does, it would take two or three months. Most likely, they would use a travel agency's European tour package.

Is it that difficult to get a visa for just tourism for a few days? What could they do to ensure that visas are issued for both of them? I hope a visa can be obtained before any money is spent on anything else related to travel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is a fairly common practice of one spouse being a dependent. No issues. They can apply together and will get the visa as same. Mention in the form or by a cover letter that the wife is a dependent. She can attach bank statement of her husband along with her. Since they are travelling together, no issues.

Also, avoid travel agents for Schengen visa and apply directly. They are likely to give wrong advice and screw up applications.

I also applied a Schengen visa for my wife, who is a dependent and got it effortlessly.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Comment: "avoid travel agents": there are several questions here describing agents who submitted false documents without their clients knowledge or consent.  The clients had to live with the consequences nonetheless.  You definitely want to have control over your own application.

Comment: I had also asked about whether obtaining a visa can be achieved before making any other purchases (like plane tickets) before travel. A reply would be appreciated. I agree about avoiding travel agents. Thanks for the heads-up. I've informed my relative about being cautious. The problem is, he's hard-pressed for time to do the necessary research. It'd have been nice if there were more straightforward procedures for tourism.

Comment: *I had also asked about whether obtaining a visa can be achieved before making any other purchases (like plane tickets) before travel.* - that's somewhat unlikely, in case of tourism usually you are expected to provide plane tickets and hotel reservations in the visa application.

Comment: @Nav For Shengen visa, you have to purchase flight tickets and make hotel reservations. Its mandatory. (Not in case of visas like UK, where they specifically says don't book till you get visa).

Comment: To @phoogs comment: The consequences of for example a travel agent applying for a visa for you and lying is that you are treated as if you had lied yourself on a visa application, which will usually lead to an automatic long-term ban. Even if there was no need for lying, that is if you had received a visa if you had said the truth.

Comment: Unbelievable! So if the visa gets rejected, the person loses some money on the plane tickets. Hotels I guess would offer a full refund. Then there's the cost of travel to the visa office, the cost of the visa application, the time lost, the days of leave one has to take from work. All this goes down the drain? If one outsources the work to an agent, that fees is lost, and there isn't even any accountability on the part of the agent. Who designed this silly process? Christopher Columbus wouldn't have stepped out of his country if this existed back then! :-)

Comment: @Nav Unlike US and UK visa, getting a Shengen visa for short term has a high chance of success. In your case, if there is no serious issues like refused entry to any country, deception and all, you have almost sure chance of getting a visa.

One other anecdote - My friend, who has kind of low salary, like 25-30k or so, got the visa recently without any issues. He was straightforward on what he was planning to do. No issues at all.

Answer (score 18):

There is no guarantee. We don't know their circumstances, we don't know what the Schengen states have in their database about them.

- The visa authorities will want to know the premise of the travel. This will be the same for both. Spouses traveling together is **normal**.
- The visa authorities will want to know who funds the travel and why. One spouse funding the travel for both husband and wife is **normal**, if the spouse who is earning money is earning enough to fund the trip.
- The visa authorities will want to be reasonably confident that both of them are tourists, and not planning to overstay.

  - Having a well-paid job at home is one factor to make a voluntary return more plausible.
  - Having no job at home is one factor to make a voluntary return less plausible.
  - A spouse having a well-paid job at home is one factor to make a return more plausible.
  - Having a spouse who stays at home is one factor to make a return more plausible.
  - Having a spouse who travels along is one factor to make a return less plausible.

Try to think about their situation. Would a visa official suspect that they would throw away their (one) job in India to stay in Europe?

Comment: Would having upcoming exams in the home country with a potential to _significantly_ increase earning potential (medical exams) on a fixed timeline also be a factor that makes a return more plausible?

Comment: @user1937198, maybe, but I would expect that a steady, transparent income by the husband will be most important.

Comment: Anything that shows ties to your home country can help: owning a house/ flat (compared to renting), having family waiting, plane tickets booked back already, etc

Comment: Just an anecdote. I don't own any fixed assets. Just a steady job. My wife was not working. We got the shengen visa, as I was going to a conference and my wife was accompanying me. I already got a UK visa (same reason) and We have a good travel history in asian countries helped.

Comment: Also, in my opinion, you are possibly overthinking this. A doctor and spouse, with a clean travel history with a good income has very less reason to overstay in Shengen area.

Answer (score 10):

I realize you are a busy professional and are accustomed to paying third parties for specialty tasks of which you are unfamiliar.   However you need to be very careful when doing that with visas and immigration. A mistake made by your contractor will affect you for the rest of your life. (I.e. being forced to tick "yes" for "were you ever refused a visa?", which brings more scrutiny at every future visa application.)

As such, your concept of entrusting your visa application **to a travel agency** is foolhardy.  They are not immigration lawyers, and they are doing the work "for free" on the side. Should a dental assistant do your job as a free extra? I think not!

I would advise either handling it yourself with great care, or having a qualified specialist do that work and only that work, for pay, and reviewing carefully everything they submit.

The fatal error in visa applications is "deception", which means putting something on the application that is wrong.  Agents do this frequently when they are in a hurry to write your application and don't know the answer to something.

Once the deception is done, there is no way to convince the authorities that it was an honest error. Because everyone says that!  (Unless of course the wrong information made you look bad, e.g. that you didn't own a house when you really did; in that case they would accept proof with an explanation of how the error occurred.  But they would not call that deception, they would call that a failure to prove tourist intent).

What immigration is mainly looking for is a body of evidence that you have no reason to want to overstay your visa and effectively immigrate, rely on public funds ("the dole"), seek employment, commit crimes, run out of money and be unable to leave, etc. Being a doctor or politician, owning a house, having ample money for the journey etc. are superb qualifications since presumably you have a successful practice which demands your return.  So is being the wife of such a person.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks. I've informed my relative to be careful. He was trying to choose travel agencies based on how low they charge. Also came across an article, where a person ended up in serious trouble because an agent submitted fake documents (https://www.rediff.com/news/special/prison-diary-38-days-in-arthur-road-jail/20170926.htm). Shouldn't something be done to ensure that agents don't do this?