# How can my girlfriend get a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, portugal

My girlfriend is a Filipina living in the United Kingdom on a work visa. I am from Portugal. We’ve been trying to start the processes for her to visit me in Portugal, but unfortunately it's not that simple.

1. Hopefully, she will be staying at my home for 2 weeks in December. How should I write the invitation letter?
2. Our goal is also to get married in Portugal. How can we do this? Does she still need a visa to get married?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing) If you’re planning for your gf to live in Portugal after you marry you should ask on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you planning to marry during the 2-week December visit?  In some countries this would have an impact on the visa application.  I don't know about Portugal.

Comment: As someone who married in Portugal, I can say that Portugal is very liberal in this matter. The legal possibility of entering a marriage is fully independent of one's citizenship and visa status.

Comment: Ad 2: Even if literally anyone can get married in Portugal, your girlfriend still needs a Schengen visa to enter Portugal in the first place.

Comment: Is she planning to move to Portugal with you?