# Refused twice a tourist visa for Finland and Estonia. Can I apply again for Poland?

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-refusals, visa-shopping

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I am staying in Egypt and have a work permit, and my husband is working too.

When I first applied for Finland with my two daughters without my husband, my first refusal was

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay, or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted,

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I applied again, increased my account but my second refusal was

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I need some advice please.

Comment: You do understand that all Schengen countries share all visa application information (i.e. Poland will see that 2 previous applications were refused and why)? Any application must be made at the consulate of your main destination during the visit.

Comment: They don’t believe your intentions are those of a genuine tourist. What is your citizenship? What is your job in Egypt? What other countries have you visited as a tourist? When were your two applications made? Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Comment: Note that while each application is supposed to be judged on its own merits, multiple refused applications from multiple Schengen countries are obvious red flags. Stop applying until you have a bullet-proof application, otherwise you just increase the chances that an application which could have been OK on the first try will be rejected because of the history.

Comment: my first demand was made in January for June vacation i applied 5 months before the supposed date and i received the answer in in May and in June i applied again to another country for July

Comment: Two refusals in 6 months indicates a vanishingly low chance of success regardless of where you apply to. Applying to different countries in an effort to get a visa looks like visa shopping and is a *bad approach*. Figure out where the weaknesses are in your personal circumstances (lack of travel history, insufficient funds, immigration status in Egypt etc etc) then wait until you’ve addressed those reasons before you try again.

Comment: I have a work permit in Egypt working in a customer service. about the travel history actualy i have a new passport can i add my old passport  during my new application with some countries stamp and should do the same countrie again i want to try with poland embassy

Comment: You should also mention why you want to visit the Schengen area, as the reason alos matters. What do you plan to do there?

Comment: I mentioned tourism as a reason with the tickets of the activities already confirmed

Answer (score 7):

You are probably not going to get a Polish visa, either.

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

Finland and Estonia do not believe that you are a genuine tourist. They think you are trying to immigrate. Part of their esimate is to compare where you are now, what you earn and how secure you are, with what you could earn if you overstay illegally in Europe and work in the illegal economy (not paying taxes, etc.).

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay

They also think you cannot afford the trip. There are cases where families pool their money together to get *one* family member into Europe, where he or she can work and send back money. Visa officials watch out for that.

> or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted,

You mentioned in a comment that you have an Egyptian work permit. They may not be certain that they can send you back to Egypt if you overstay in Europe. Your citizenship matters, not just your place of residence.

Comment: According to you what will be the solution now because I would like to apply for Poland as there I would be subject to an interview instead of going through VSF is that it will be a good idea for a third country because soon the opening of classes for my daughter or I redo a new application also for Estonia while clearly explaining my intentions because in my motivation I just mention tourism spend time with my two daughters

Comment: @YoussoufKourouma, I cannot answer that without knowing your circumstances. It may not be possible anytime soon. It would help if you had a stable job in Egypt where you earn more than average people in Poland or the Baltics.

Comment: i am working in a call center here with my husband but many of my friend used to go and come back for vacation i was thinking to confirmed my hotel reservations and to buy a refundable ticket  maybe they can be sur i will be back in egypt

Comment: To the OP: What is your nationality?

Comment: i am from guinea