# new application after two refusal

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I have been refused twice a tourist visa for Finland and Estonia the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable. now I have got an invitation letter from France do I still have a chance should apply again for tourist or visit visa. Should I add my plan itinerary and activities?? the one who sent me the invitation letter is my sponsor but i am also working here in Egypt married with two children I am going with my daughters for vacation?

Comment: A few weeks ago you were asking about a third application for Poland, and you were told you unlikely to get it.  This applies to France too unless something significant has changed about your circumstances.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182241/refused-twice-for-tourist-visa-for-finland-and-estonia-can-i-apply-again-for-po

Comment: What do you mean by "invitation letter"? Is this an organization that wants you to do something? Or just a private person who would like you to visit them. Is that person going to pay all your costs? Why are they inviting you?

Comment: It was my aunt who decided to send me an invitation letter for 10 days with full support.

Answer (score 7):

> do I still have a chance should I apply again for tourist or visit visa?

Highly unlikely, unless your circumstances have changed significantly since your two refusals. The answer to your recent previous question [Refused twice for tourist visa for Finland and Estonia. Can I apply again for Poland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182241/refused-twice-for-tourist-visa-for-finland-and-estonia-can-i-apply-again-for-po) still applies.

> Should I add my plan itinerary and activities?

This is a standard requirement when applying, you certainly **won’t** get a visa if you don’t.