# I live in Morocco and I work remotely for a Canadian company. Can I have a Schengen tourist visa to France?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

I want to visit my friend who lives in France on my next holiday. Since I work remotely for a Canadian company (with an independent contract), I would like to know, if I apply to a Schengen visa, is there a chance that it can be accepted?

Knowing that my friend is willing to send me an invitation for accommodation.

Comment: What is your citizenship?  A good job, whether with a Canadian company or not, will help.  The invitation should help as well.  Nobody here can say that you will certainly get or not get a visa.  Try to make the case that you have something to come home to and won't overstay.  Do it honestly with supporting evidence.

Comment: How long have you been working for that company? On average, how much do you earn? Did you set up your own company, or do you at least have separate business and personal accounts? Do you have tax returns, company accounts, salary slips, or some other evidence which could be used to show your earnings?

Comment: Well I just started with them its my first month, I Earn 850$ a month, I dont have my own company unfortunatley, My personal account is the same one that receives my salary, I can request salary slips if I would need it from my employer. In morocco employers that has employees need to declare them on the The National Social Security Fund but since I work with a canadian company I dont have the option of doing it myself that's why I was wondering if there is another way to prove that I want only to visit France as a tourist :/

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing

Comment: The graphic in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy-intention-to-leave-could-not-be-ascer) explains how your application would be likely to be assessed. If your personal profile is eg ‘young, no family/ties, no/little prior travel history, remote-working employment’ (plus maybe ‘invitation from internet-only friend’) you’d be much more likely to be refused.