# What should the Employer letter contain for a part-time employee?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, business-travel, proof-of-employment

I serve as a part-time teaching assistant at a university in my country. I am applying for a Schengen business visa where I will be participating in an academic conference at a research institute in Germany and that institute is going to fund my participation, travel expenses and accomendation during my stay there.

What should the employer letter contain?

Can you show me a template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)

Answer (score -3):

Here is a template for an employer letter for a Schengen Business Visa:

[Employer’s letterhead]

[Date]

[Embassy Name and Address]

To Whom it May Concern,

I am writing this letter to confirm that [Your Name] is employed at [Name of University/Institution] as a part-time teaching assistant. We hereby confirm that [Your Name] has been granted permission to attend the academic conference at [Name of Research Institute] in Germany from [Date of Arrival] to [Date of Departure]. The conference is a part of [Your Field of Study] and will be a great opportunity for [Your Name] to broaden her/his knowledge and network with other professionals in the field.

[Your Name] will be fully sponsored by [Name of Research Institute] during her/his stay in Germany, including all travel expenses, accommodation, and conference fees. [Your Name] will be staying at [Name and Address of Accommodation] for the entire duration of the conference.

We hereby guarantee that [Your Name] will return to [Your Home Country] immediately after the conference and will not breach any immigration laws during the trip. She/he will resume her/his work at [Name of University/Institution] upon her/his return, as per the agreed employment terms.

Thank you for considering [Your Name]’s application for a Schengen Business Visa. Please do not hesitate to contact us if you require any further information.

Yours faithfully,

[Your Name and Position]

[Name of University/Institution]

[Contact Information]

Comment: Did you write this yourself, or is it based on a template you found elsewhere? I'm very skeptical about the first sentence of the third paragraph ("We hereby guarantee..."). The employer is in no position to make those guarantees.

Comment: The first part of the penultimate paragraph is completely inappropriate, not to mention worthless. An  employer cannot make such a guarantee.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I just want to give example not exactly this one it's just a template.