# How easy is it to get Schengen visa for Indian citizen and Canadian PR? How long could it take?

Tags: visas, schengen, canada, europe

Okay, I am thinking of doing a eurotrip in December.

I have been in Canada since 4 years, and currently a PR. Indian citizenship.

Before this I've had US Visa for 5 years and lived there.

How long could it generally take the get the Schengen visa for me, and what documents could be required?

Would I need an agent to apply, or like it is easy so I can apply?

Comment: Your citizenship will matter. Please add it. The PR will help, of course.

Comment: Title says Indian citizen.

Comment: Which Schengen country(ies)? What has the research you’ve done so far revealed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to do some research first. The answer to ‘what documents are required’ can easily be found via a quick google search, while some of the question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Many things will depend on the destination country. But in general, once the documents are submitted, it may take about 2 weeks to get the decision. This period can be extended to 1 or 2 months but personally I have never experienced this (but I am not an Indian citizen so YMMV). Again, depending on the destination country, the toughest part may be getting an appointment to submit the documents. The closest available dates may be several months ahead.

For a touristic trip, they could ask for a proof of residency, employment details, itinerary/hotels/air ticket reservations (usually no need to buy, only reserve), financial means, health insurance, and photos.

Agents are usually not required, you can submit the documents by yourself. Sometimes, directly to the embassy/consulate, sometimes they ask you to submit the docs through an intermediary like VFS. Again, depends on the destination country.

Comment: I see. I somehow thought that I would be able to visit all the countries, and like do a multi-country eurotrip like many people do ... <think>

Comment: @10101010 There are rules on how to apply when planning a multi-country trip. [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing) gives pretty much all the information you’ll need. See [this list](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates) for other commonly-asked questions about Schengen visas.

Comment: @10101010 you can visit multiple countries but you will apply for a visa only to one, which is the main destination

Comment: Okay thanks, frankly my country of landing will depend on flight to whichever is cheapest. I hope it is okay if I land in country other than one applied to ... Is it okay?

Comment: @10101010 , visa application country should be the one of your main destination or where you want to spend the longest time, but not necessarily the first one where you land. So yes, it is ok to land in a different country. But they will ask for your itinerary anyways, including airplane ticket reservations

Comment: Thanks, by longest time, you mean most time right? 
So if I apply to Czech, does this work:

Prague for 5 days, Budapest for 3, Paris for 3 and so on .. etc..

Comment: @10101010 yes, if you plan to spend 5 days in Czechia and 3 days in each of the other countries, then you can apply for a visa in a Czech embassy